# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'wells.id' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, laravel

tengo un problema con mi consulta, tengo en mi base dos tablas wells (id,pozo, profundidad, etc) y well_interventions (id, well_id, fecha, obs,motivo,etc)

tengo una vista blade con una tabla que me muestra todas las intervenciones con sus nombre de pozo respectivo, puse en esa tabla un input para buscar por diferentas campos
y en mi modelo WellIntervention quiero crear una función buscar uniendo las dos tablas relacionadas y me da el error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'wells.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `well_interventions` as `wi` inner join `well_interventions` on `wells`.`id` = `well_interventions`.`well_id` inner join `wells` on `wells`.`id` = `well_interventions`.`well_id` where `wi`.`fecha` like %9% or `wi`.`motivo` like %9% or `wells`.`pozo` like %9% or `wi`.`obs` like %9%)

mi modelo WellInterventions

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class WellIntervention extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'area_id',    
        'well_id',    
        'fecha',
        'motivo',
        'obs'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'fecha' => 'datetime:d-m-Y',
    ];

    
     

    public static function search($query){
        return empty($query) ? static::query()
       : $search= DB::table('well_interventions as wi')
        ->join('well_interventions', 'wells.id', '=', 'well_interventions.well_id')
        ->join('wells', 'wells.id', '=', 'well_interventions.well_id')
        ->select('well_interventions.*','wells.pozo')
        ->where('wi.fecha', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
        ->orWhere('wi.motivo', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')              
        ->orWhere('wells.pozo', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')              
        ->orWhere('wi.obs', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');                

    }

    public function well(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Well::class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Para qué es el primer join, si ya estas consultando esa tabla?

Comment: Proble tantas maneras y una de las preguntas que vi, solucionaba, pero a mi no

Comment: Probablemente por eso te lanza la excepción.

Comment: si saco primer join me arroja SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'well_interventions.well_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `well_interventions` as `wi` inner join `wells` on `wells`.`id` = `well_interventions`.`well_id` where `wi`.`fecha` like %9% or `wi`.`motivo` like %9% or `wells`.`pozo` like %9% or `wi`.`obs` like %9%)

Comment: Porque le pusiste un alias, a la tabla te tienes que referir por el alias que le pusiste, como haces en los where

Comment: el 9 que aparece es el pozo que quese buscar que sellama cco-95, tengo todos los pozos con un prefijo

Comment: Me refiero a que si hiciste `table('well_interventions as wi')`, ya no uses `well_interventions` sino `wi`, en el join y en el select

Comment: muchas gracias @porloscerrosΨ ahora te paso como quedo mi funcion y si resulta perfecto

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo las instrucciones en los comentarios bajo la pregunta, mi modelo quedó asi:

```php
    public static function search($query)
    {
        return empty($query) ? static::query()
            : static::join('wells', 'wells.id', '=', 'well_interventions.well_id')
            ->select('well_interventions.*','wells.pozo')
            ->Where('fecha', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')              
            ->orWhere('motivo', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')              
            ->orWhere('pozo', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')               
            ->orWhere('obs', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');                
                  
    }
```